# The safest way to automate WordPress backups

Tags: plugins, security, backup

I'm running over 20+ sites on a Linux shared cloud environment. At present, my hosting company performs daily, offsite backups. However, these are only kept for 30 days.

This works great, but what if one of my sites got infected and I didn't notice for 60 days? I'd be left with a series of backups that were all infected.

This led me to conduct some research into automated backups and backup plugins.

I have found 2 excellent premium solutions ([Updraft Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/) & [BackUpWordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/backupwordpress/)) that will back up each site and send a copy to Google Drive.

**My questions**

1) If a site got hacked with either plugin installed, what could a hacker do with the Cloud API information (e.g Google Drive) that I have provided? Could the attacker access the backups or add files to the backups?

2) With [Updraft Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/), my database will be encrypted, but is it really a good idea to be placing my database on a cloud platform like Google Drive?

3) Is there a safer solution to backing up your WordPress site e.g. setting up a cron job and keeping local backups instead?

Comment: You should take a look at https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-restore-your-wordpress-website-with-codeguard--cms-23426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Partial answer as I'm familiar with AWS, not Google Drive.)

Having a WordPress DB stored somewhere on a cloud service is, in my opinion, no worse that hosting the site on a virtual or cloud server (given virtualisation platforms all allow you to reset the server's root password - albeit typically with a reboot - so your entire machine is at risk if someone discovers your control panel logon.)

Make sure you've followed [basic security precautions](https://www.linode.com/backups) for your server and also consider the [two-factor-auth](https://wordpress.org/plugins/two-factor-auth/) plugin that, even with at it's lowest security, will send a one-time password to the user's email address when they login (a user's email would need to be hacked as well for the hacker to gain access to the WordPress dashboard.)

Personally, many of my sites use Linode. I use [their backup service](https://www.linode.com/backups) as a precaution, but you can only fully restore the entire drive, so it's no help if you accidentally deleting a single file or directory and want to leave everything else that has changed on the machine since the backup was taken intact.

[backup2l](http://backup2l.sourceforge.net/) is a free/simple/reliable command line backup utility that lets you recover files individually. It uses well known Linux commands like `tar` and `gzip`. (There are packages for it in most distributions, no need to install manually.)

By default it runs daily, but it does incremental backups so you can configure as often as you like.

I use the following code in my `/etc/backup2l.conf` to automatically dump the SQL databases before the backup runs:

```
# This user-defined bash function is executed before a backup is made
PRE_BACKUP ()
{
    # e. g., shut down some mail/db servers if their files are to be backup'ed

    # On a Debian system, the following statements dump a machine-readable list of
    # all installed packages to a file.

    echo "  writing dpkg selections to /root/.dpkg-selections.log..."
    dpkg --get-selections | diff - /root/.dpkg-selections.log > /dev/null || dpkg --get-selections > /root/.dpkg-selections.log

    echo " dumping databases"
    for i in /var/lib/mysql/*/; do
        name=`basename $i`

        # get username + password
        user=$(grep user /etc/mysql/debian.cnf | awk '{print $3}' | head -n 1)
        pass=$(grep pass /etc/mysql/debian.cnf | awk '{print $3}' | head -n 1)

        # do the dump
        mysqldump --user="$user" --password="$pass" --ignore-table=mysql.event $name | gzip > /var/backups/mysql/$name.gz
    done

}
```

Then in POST_BACKUP, I upload the backup files to an Amazon S3 bucket with [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd):

```
# This user-defined bash function is executed after a backup is made
POST_BACKUP ()
{
    # e. g., restart some mail/db server if its files are to be backup'ed/
    /usr/bin/s3cmd sync -c /home/myhomedir/.s3cfg --delete-removed /var/backups/localhost/ s3://my-bucket-name/
}
```

AWS has "[Versioning](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#Data_Protection)" which means that if someone gained access to your server and used the IAM credentials to delete the backup files from your bucket, you'd still be able to get them back.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I'll leave this for 24 hours to see if anyone with Google Drive experience leaves an answer.